# Terraform: How to install PS Modules from Gallery into Azure Automation?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-automation

how can I install a PowerShel module from the Gallery into my azure Automation Account using Terraform?

I tried using powershellgallery API url:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_account" "aac" {
  name                = var.azure_automation_account_name
  location            = var.location
  tags                = var.tags
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  sku_name = "Basic"
}

resource "azurerm_automation_module" "az_accounts" {
  name                    = "az_accounts"
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.aac.name

  module_link {
    uri = "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/az.accounts/2.2.4"
  }
}
```

This allways gets me an error (I tried several modules with different versions, made no difference):

```
Error: Error waiting for Module "az_accounts" (Automation Account "XXX" / Resource Group "YYY") to finish provisioning: Orchestrator.Shared.AsyncModuleImport.ModuleImportException: Cannot import the module of name az_accounts, as the module structure was invalid.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module name should be `"Az.Accounts"`. This works for me.

```
resource "azurerm_automation_module" "example" {
  name                    = "Az.Accounts"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name

  module_link {
    uri = "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/az.accounts/2.2.4"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works for me as well... my bad, I wasn't aware that the name actually matters...